# PyCharm Pyramid project using pyramid_mongodb scaffold: How to?

Tags: pycharm, pymongo, pyramid

I'm using PyCharm to develop my Pyramid projects.  I'd like to use the pyramid_pymongo scaffold instead of the standard scaffolds that PyCharm knows about.  How can I add a scaffold for Pyramid projects to PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, the list of scaffolds available when you are using PyCharm's "New Project" Pyramid support is limited to the scaffolds that Pyramid ships with. You will unfortunately need to do it manually, then open the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own scaffold for your Pyramid projects. Instructions for doing so are in the official Pyramid documentation, [Creating Pyramid Scaffolds](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/scaffolding.html).